# PROLOG - check if file exists

Tags: prolog, exists

In my program I want to first check if a certain file exists. If it does I want to read it, if not I want to create it (using tell) and work with it. I can't get Prolog to check if a file exists.

I've tried

```
exists_file('testfile.pl')
exists('testfile.pl')
access_file('testfile.pl',exists)
```

For all three I get the message "existence error ... does not exist"

What's wrong here?
What I want is a predicate that returns true or false, depending on whether the file exists or not.

Thanks

Comment: What prolog version are you using? `exists_file/1` works for me in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: tell & told are *really* old school - maybe even deprecated. Use open & close instead

Comment: There is no Prolog standard file system API. Different systems provide different built-in predicates or libraries to check if a file exists. See your Prolog system documentation. You can also find how different systems do it e.g. at https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/os.lgt

Comment: I'm using SICStus Prolog 4.4.1. I still don't understand why it doesn't work. When I type `exists_file('testfile.pl')`, I get "Existence error in user:exists_file/1. procedure user:exists_file/1 does not exist. (It doesn't have anything to do with the "user:" part, does it?)

Comment: In SICStus there is a predicate `file_exists` (see https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.1/html/sicstus/lib_002dfile_005fsystems.html which is for 4.3.1 but probably the predicate is still available in 4.4.1).

Comment: Well, `file_exists` didn't work, so I defined it myself: `file_exists(File):-absolute_file_name(File, _,[access([exist]),file_errors(fail)]).` Thx everyone.